# Can you link a TFS Work Item to a OneNote Task?

Tags: tfs, onenote

My company uses Team Foundation Server for project tracking.  I use OneNote for personal organization.  It would be really sweet if I could link a OneNote task to an associated TFS Work Item and track them together.  Can you do this?  Has any such integration been attempted in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a commercial product that has a minor integration.  It seems that this is really not a supported feature.

http://www.componentsource.com/products/ekobit-teamcompanion/summary.html

Comment: If you've found anything since (preferably free), I'm curious.

Comment: No, I have not found anything else.